# i have a problem with the get method from a webapi to angularjs and html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I was trying to develop a website using Front-End HTML and AngularJS. I also have a WebApi Hosted online. i was trying to get the data from the WebApi which is in JSON Format using angularjs controller http get method and display it using ng-repeat directive but I'm not getting the data, there is some problem in getting the data from the WebApi. The WebApi is created using asp.net c# WebApi. The Code the Website is here (Its a blog website) -

blogController.js :

```
app.controller('blogController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://www.example.com/api/blog')
      .then(function(res){
        $scope.blog = res.data;
    });
}]);
```

The HTML Code is here below -

Blog.html

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body app="myApp" ng-controller="blogController">
      <div ng-repeat="blg in blog">
         <h2>{{blg.BLOG_TITLE}}</h2><br/><br/><hr/>

         <p>{{blg.BLOG_DESC}}</p><br/>
         <p>{{blg.BLOG_AUTHOR}}</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The Json WebApi looks like this -

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1.0,
    "BLOG_DATE": "2020-05-02T00:00:00",
    "BLOG_AUTHOR": 1.0,
    "IMG_URL": null,
    "BLOG_TITLE": "Test Blog",
    "SHORT_DESC": "Blog 1",
    "BLOG_DESC": "Blog1 Desc",
    "NOTE": null,
    "BLOG_TAG": "Uncategorized"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2.0,
    "BLOG_DATE": "2020-05-02T00:00:00",
    "BLOG_AUTHOR": 1.0,
    "IMG_URL": null,
    "BLOG_TITLE": "Test Blog",
    "SHORT_DESC": "Blog 1",
    "BLOG_DESC": "Blog1 Desc",
    "NOTE": null,
    "BLOG_TAG": "Uncategorized"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3.0,
    "BLOG_DATE": "2020-05-02T00:00:00",
    "BLOG_AUTHOR": 1.0,
    "IMG_URL": null,
    "BLOG_TITLE": "Test Blog",
    "SHORT_DESC": "Blog 1",
    "BLOG_DESC": "Blog1 Desc",
    "NOTE": null,
    "BLOG_TAG": "Uncategorized"
  },
  {
    "ID": 4.0,
    "BLOG_DATE": "2020-05-02T00:00:00",
    "BLOG_AUTHOR": 1.0,
    "IMG_URL": null,
    "BLOG_TITLE": "Test Blog",
    "SHORT_DESC": "Blog 1",
    "BLOG_DESC": "Blog1 Desc",
    "NOTE": null,
    "BLOG_TAG": "Uncategorized"
  }
]
```

The problem is occuring only with the url which is in the above controller. I have tried using another url, a url from myjson.com, it worked. But the "http://www.example.com/api/blog" doesn't works.

**Please help me to solve this problem.**

Comment: Is the URL definitely returning data? If you type the URL into a browser, does it return the expected JSON?

Comment: Use the network tab in the Developer Console to check the request and response. It is likely a CORS problem.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a clear problem description. what exactly is the error message? check in the network tab, click on the specific request which is probably in red and see the error message. This is part of debugging / troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `.catch` block to display errors:

```
app.controller('blogController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://www.example.com/api/blog')
      .then(function(res){
        $scope.blog = res.data;
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR:", response);
    });
}]);
```

Then check the response in the network tab of the Developer Console.